# Is there a way to make a single query in MongoDB for different types of documents and limit each type to a specific number in one collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Let's say I have a collection called "pets"

The collection contains three different types of pets: **cat**, **dog**, and **bird**

Now let's say there are 10 cats, 10 dogs, and 10 birds in the collection (30 documents in total).

Is there a way to make a single query to pets that gets me 3 cats, 2 dogs, and 1 bird?

Basically I want to specify each type of pet I want, and limit each type of pet to a specific number, all in one query. The reason for this is because I want to be efficient and not make many queries.

This is what I have currently:

```
  const docs = await db.collection('pets');

  const cats = await docs
  .find({ type: 'cat' })
  .limit(3)
  .toArray();

  const dogs = await docs
  .find({ type: 'dog' })
  .limit(2)
  .toArray();

  const birds = await docs
  .find({ type: 'bird' })
  .limit(1)
  .toArray();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You can use an aggregate query. Using the [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) stage gives you a solution with one query.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to prasad_, here is the solution that solves my case:

```
  const docs = await db.collection('pets')
  .aggregate([
    {
      $facet: {
        'cats': [
          { $match: { type: 'cat' } },
          { $limit: 3 },
        ],
        'dogs': [
          { $match: { type: 'dog' } },
          { $limit: 2 },
        ],
        'birds': [
          { $match: { type: 'bird' } },
          { $limit: 1 },
        ],
      },
    },
  ])
  .toArray();
```